# DOM elements not loading causes 'undefined' error

Tags: javascript, html, css, undefined

for a project where I'm building a website I have the following JS code:

```
load();

function load(){
  addHeader(...);
  addNav(...);
  addMenu(...);
  addPosterTrailer(...);
  addPlot();
  addCastCrew();

  document.querySelector('select#scope').addEventListener('change', changeScope);
}

function addHeader(header, movie) {...}

function addNav(nav, ...navitems) {...}

function addPosterTrailer(section, movie) {...}

function addPlot(section, movie) {...}

function addCastCrew(section, castcrew) {..}

function addMenu(footer) {...}

function changeScope(event) {
  var postertrailer = document.querySelector('div.postertrailer');
  var poster        = document.querySelector('div.postertrailer img');
  var trailer       = document.querySelector('div.postertrailer iframe');
  var separators    = document.querySelectorAll('div.separator');
  var plot          = document.querySelector('div.page-discription');
  var castcrew      = document.querySelector('div.castgrid');
  var all           = [poster, trailer, plot, castcrew].concat(separators);
  
  switch (event.target.value) {
    case 'All':
      visibleExcept(null, all);
      break;
    case 'Poster':
      visibleExcept(poster, all);
      break;
    case 'Trailer':
      visibleExcept(trailer, all);
      break;
    case 'Plot':
      visibleExcept(plot, all);
      break;
    case 'Cast & Crew':
      visibleExcept(castcrew, all);
      break;
  }
}

function visibleExcept(exception, all) {
  for (let element of all) {
    if (element != exception) {
      element.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    } else {
      element.style.visibility = 'visible'
    }
  }
}
```

producing the following html:

```
<html lang="nl">
  <head>
    <title>Info</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Slab:wght@200;500;600&amp;family=Zilla+Slab:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;1,300&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/general.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/info.css">
    <meta name="description" content="Foto's from The Grand Budapest Hotel by Wes Anderson">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Auke Roest">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="module" src="../javascript/info.js"></script>
    <style data-emotion="css"></style>
  </head>
  <body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
    <header>
      <h1 class="header__title">The Grand Budapest Hotel (2014)</h1>
      <span class="header__credits">A Wes Anderson Comedy</span>
    </header>
    <nav class="navbar"><a class="navbaritem" href="../html/index.html" title="Home">Home</a><a class="navbaritem" href="../html/castcrew.html" title="Cast &amp; Crew">Cast &amp; Crew</a><a class="navbaritem" href="../html/reviews.html" title="Reviews">Reviews</a><a class="navbaritem" href="../html/plot.html" title="Plot">Plot</a><a class="navbaritem" href="../html/photos.html" title="Photos">Photos</a><a class="navbaritem" href="../html/info.html" title="Info">Info</a></nav>
    <section>
      <div class="separator" id="postertrailer">Movie Poster and Trailer</div>
      <div class="postertrailer">
        <img class="poster" src="../images/otherimages/gbhcover.jpg" alt="Grand Budapest Hotel Cover">
        <iframe class="trailer" ... ></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="separator" id="plot">Plot</div>
      <div class="page-discription">
        <p>In the 1930s, the Grand Budapest Hotel is a popular European ski resort, presided over by concierge Gustave H. (Ralph Fiennes). Zero, a junior lobby boy, becomes Gustave's friend and protege. Gustave prides himself on providing first-class service to the hotel's guests, including satisfying the sexual needs of the many elderly women who stay there. When one of Gustave's lovers dies mysteriously, Gustave finds himself the recipient of a priceless painting and the chief suspect in her murder.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="separator" id="castcrew">Cast &amp; Crew</div>
      <div class="castgrid">
        <div class="cast-grid__cell">
          <div><span class="cast-grid__cell_name">Wes Anderson</span><span class="cast-grid__cell_role">Director</span></div>
          <a href="../html/cast.html"><img class="ccimg" width="100" src="../images/cast/wesanderson.webp" alt="Wes Anderson"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="cast-grid__cell">
          <div><span class="cast-grid__cell_name">Hugo Guiness</span><span class="cast-grid__cell_role">Writer</span></div>
          <a href="../html/cast.html"><img class="ccimg" width="100" src="../images/cast/hugoguiness.png" alt="Hugo Guiness"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="cast-grid__cell">
          <div><span class="cast-grid__cell_name">Ralph Fiennes</span><span class="cast-grid__cell_role">Gustav H.</span></div>
          <a href="../html/cast.html"><img class="ccimg" width="100" src="../images/actors/ralphfiennes.jpg" alt="Ralph Fiennes"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="cast-grid__cell">
          <div><span class="cast-grid__cell_name">Adrien Brody</span><span class="cast-grid__cell_role">Dmitri</span></div>
          <a href="../html/cast.html"><img class="ccimg" width="100" src="../images/actors/adrienbrody.jpg" alt="Adrien Brody"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="cast-grid__cell">
          <div><span class="cast-grid__cell_name">Tony Revolori</span><span class="cast-grid__cell_role">Zero</span></div>
          <a href="../html/cast.html"><img class="ccimg" width="100" src="../images/actors/tonyrevolori.jpg" alt="Tony Revolori"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="cast-grid__cell">
          <div><span class="cast-grid__cell_name">Tilda Swinton</span><span class="cast-grid__cell_role">Madame D.</span></div>
          <a href="../html/cast.html"><img class="ccimg" width="100" src="../images/actors/tildaswinton.jpg" alt="Tilda Swinton"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <div class="footer__container">
        <label for="scope">Scope: </label>
        <select class="footer__select" id="scope">
          <option value="All">All</option>
          <option value="Poster">Poster</option>
          <option value="Trailer">Trailer</option>
          <option value="Plot">Plot</option>
          <option value="Cast &amp; Crew">Cast &amp; Crew</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="footer__container"><label for="setting">Setting: </label><select class="footer__select" id="setting"></select></div>
    </footer>
    <!-- Code injected by live-server -->
    <div id="850bf1df-eb3c-4cce-b3be-b2900ccc29b8-quickmenu"></div>
  </body>
```

When running this, I get the following error:

```
info.js:221 
Uncaught ReferenceError: poster is not defined
    at invisibleExcept (info.js:221:16)
    at HTMLSelectElement.changeScope (info.js:199:7)
```

I'm guessing this is because some elements have not yet been loaded in and can therefor not be found and edited. How do I resolve this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: No, the issue is in the `changeScope` function, where you write `var separators    = document.querySelectorAll('div.separator');`. This returns an iterable, so it doesn't have a property `style`.

Comment: why are you adding a eventlistener to the window-object. you can just  load() on top of your file; not an answer just interested what the puropse of it is

Comment: @code apologies, i fixed this after i started writing this post but i still get errors, i will edit the question

Comment: Need html markup as well please

Comment: On a modern JS sidenote: don't use `var`. Either use `let` or `const` (depending on whether you need mutable or immutables), both of which are scoped to blocks, as you would expect. `var` is a much older way to declare an execution-context-scoped variable, leading to hilarious things like your var already existing "before" your code seems to declare it. Just say no to `var`, and stick with `let` and `const`.